# PostgreSQL FTS exact search

Tags: postgresql

Hello everyone I reread all the documentation of full-text search and the following question arose:
How to perform an accurate word search using Postgresql ?
For example, I have 100 document titles.

```
Names:
Document 
Document red 
The document is green outdated
```

I want to send a "Document" request and get only the Document, and not see the rest in the search results.
This is possible by means of Postgresql FTS?

I read all the documentation on full-text search and did not see such possibilities and examples

Comment: What is the purpose of doing the FTS for an exact match? Why not just do a regular comparison?

Comment: The goal is to search for exact phrases. postgresql FTS itself is already in use and I would like to continue using it for a new purpose. Shows a quick search among a lot of data by words. There are certain phrases consisting of 2-3 words that the user wants to search for with word accuracy.

Comment: I see. Maybe you could use `to_tsphrase` in conjunction with a word count?

Comment: Tell me where to read about it I can't find a description of this function? 
This will allow you to find only exact phrases or words (if the preposition consists of one word). I would appreciate an example, since it is difficult to understand myself. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I misremembered the name. As you can see from the answer someone else provided, I meant `phraseto_tsquery`. Although I think if you want an exact match, you'll still need additional logic (such as a count of the words).

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is just not to build yet another index, you can write a FTS query to use the index, and combine it with a simple AND equality check to rule out the things the index returns but which you don't want:

```
WHERE doc = 'Document' AND
      tsv @@ phraseto_tsquery('english','Document')
```